# Is there a way to change web chat font size in IE11

Tags: azure, botframework, web-chat

I have created a chat bot on the directline channel for all browsers, **including** IE11.

I need to change the font size of the user and bot messages. I have found a way to do this for all browsers bar IE11 (due to ES5).

I have tried to find ways to do this; including looking for styleOptions in the defaultStyleOptions.js

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleOptions.js

To which there are no options available.

There is an option, however, in the createSetStyle method of WebChat that allows the font size to be changed.

```
const styleSet = window.WebChat.createStyleSet({});

styleSet.textContent = {
    fontSize: '24px'
};

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({token: conversationToken}),
    styleSet
}, document.getElementById("chatbot-display"));
```

Though this option does **not** work in IE11 (ES5)

I expect to be able to find an option which allows me to change the font size of the chat message text. i.e. fontSize: 12px.

Comment: This looks a duplicate of https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2306

Comment: @tdurnford Yeah I posted the question on the BotFramework GitHub as well. I thought it would be a good place to have it as well as here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a method from WebChat to do this.

However, I was able to find a work around.

```
.bubble {
font-size: 24px !important;
}
```